# Sencha Touch Vbox

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have below requirement of a page with sencha touch:

1. A drop down of some options
2. A question posted by users (length may vary big time)
3. a text area to display get the answer
4. Two buttons for submit and ignore

I am using vbox layout. Now the problem is I want the page to be fully scrollable instead of partial scrolls on dataview etc.

How can I achieve it. I have similar requirements for different screens.

Below is the code:

```
Ext.define('HCMDoctor.view.PFQuestion', {
        extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
        xtype : 'PFQuestion',
        id : 'pfView',
        config : {
            layout : {
                type : 'vbox',
                align : 'stretch'
            },
            flex : 1,
            scrollable : true,
            items : [{
                        xtype : 'container',
                        html : 'Public Forum Question' 
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'selectfield',
                        store : 'CommunityWiseQuestions',
                        name : 'pfCommId',
                        id : 'pfCommId',
                        valueField : 'communityId',
                        displayField : 'displayFull'
                    }, {
                        store : 'PFQuestion',
                        xtype : 'dataview',
                        flex : 1,
                        id : 'pfQuestionHolder',
                        itemTpl : ['{discussionTitle}<br>{description}',
                                '<br>Posted in {postedInCommunityName}']
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'hiddenfield',
                        id : 'pfQuestionId',
                        name : 'pfQuestionId'

                    }, {
                        xtype : 'textareafield',
                        id : 'pfAnswer',
                        name : 'pfAnswer'
                    }, {
                        store : 'PFQuestion',
                        xtype : 'button',
                        text : 'Ignore',
                        id : 'ignorePFQuestion'
                    }, {
                        store : 'PFQuestion',
                        xtype : 'button',
                        text : 'Submit',
                        id : 'submitPFQuestion'
                    }

            ]

        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: why is `pfQuestionHolder` a `dataview`? It could very well be a `Panel` with `data` & `tpl` attribute to achieve what you want.

Comment: when u say data do you mean it to be hardcoded? I need the data from the server... If you can suggest me a way to have a panel with store or applying store data I am fully fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onload of store iterate over records and in every iteration create panel with `tpl` by passing record data to it and add the panel to its parent. something like this:

```
var parentPanel = Ext.getCmp("pfView");
for(var i=0; i++; i<records.size){
    var mypanel = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
        data    : records[i]
    });
    parentPanel.add(myPanel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ThinkFloyd. Do you have any way to pupulate a list also in similar manner?? Or having a template with for loop and passing the array is appropriate??

Comment: Since List uses data from store you can add records in store and refresh, it should work